# Seeking help in a basic, bare bones method of creating a 2D OpenGL-ES 2.0 Game

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, game-loop

I have made many Android applications that use Java code and the XML layouts, however I am very new to OpenGL ES. I have programmed games in Swing Java, including pong, and an intermediate level 2d platformer (with a map editor, too!). I have extensive knowledge in Java, however, OpenGL is a new doorway I wish to open.

Using guides online, I have made simple things in OpenGL ES, including a cube that I manually mapped the co-ordinates for (which was a very fun experience), and drawing a triangle on the screen.

My question is, how can I make a 2d game with OpenGL ES? Now, what I've tried doesn't quite work well, as the images I draw arent to scale, and no matter what guide I use, the image is always choppy and not the right size on my Nexus S that I am debugging to.

What I need to learn to do is, be able to draw images and objects to the screen with OpenGL ES, and learn how to perform a game loop. I havent looked into a game loop in Android, but will soon. What I want to master first is drawing crisp, HD images to the screen, which just won't work for me.

If you require me to post examples of what I have done in the past, of course I will. But I am hoping you can help me with a fresh start. Thank you.

***TL;DR:*** How to draw crisp, HD, 2D images to the screen using OpenGL ES, and how to have a game loop in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably heard of Cocos2d, a 2d gaming framework that works as a wrapper on OpenGL.
It was originally developed for iOS, but it was ported to Android to.

The project page:
https://github.com/ZhouWeikuan/cocos2d/tree/master/cocos2d-android

Great starters guide:
http://dan.clarke.name/2011/04/how-to-make-a-simple-android-game-with-cocos2d/